# 3 nested for-each loops as Java Stream (or better parallel stream)

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

On the project I am currently working on, we have this construct of three nested for loops:

```
List<OutputDataType> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

for (OrgStructureEntity product : products) {

       for (String region : regions) {

                for (SalesType salesType : SalesType.values()) {

                    resultList.addAll(new SalesRequest(getConnection(),
                            product.getProductMainGroup(), product.getSbu(), planYear, currentPeriod, region, salesType,
                            exchangeRates).calculateSalesKpis());
                }    
       }
}
```

products and regions are both Sets.
resultList is an ArrayList with "OutputDataType" objects.
The method calculateSalesKpis() also returns a list of "OutputDataType" objects.
All these objects are supposed to be added to the resultList. I would like to do all this with parallel streams to make it faster, but I didn't get much further than this:

```
products.stream()
                .map(product -> regions.stream()
                        .map(region -> Arrays.stream(SalesType.values())
                                .map(salesType -> new SalesRequest(getConnection(),
                                        product.getProductMainGroup(), product.getSbu(), planYear, currentPeriod, region, salesType,
                                        exchangeRates).calculateSalesKpis())))
                .
```

I don't know how to put it all in the result list now and how to close the stream correctly.
I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Use .collect(Collectors.toList())  terminal operation to collect your result in list

Comment: You mean just where that last dot is? That unfortunately doesn't work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to avoid working on Stream>, you need to flatten your nested `Stream` structure using the `flatmap` method before performing a collection:

```
products.stream()
  .flatMap(product -> regions.stream()
    .flatMap(region -> Arrays.stream(SalesType.values())
     .flatMap(salesType -> new SalesRequest(getConnection(),
       product.getProductMainGroup(), product.getSbu(), planYear, currentPeriod, region, salesType, exchangeRates).calculateSalesKpis().stream())))
  .collect(Collectors.toList())

            .
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I think it's because calculateSalesKpis() does not return a single OutputDataType object but a list of OutputDatatype objects...

Comment: collect (java.util.stream.Collector<? super java.util.List<fourschlag.entities.types.OutputDataType>,A,R>) in Stream cannot be applied
to
(java.util.stream.Collector<T,capture<?>,java.util.List<T>>)

Comment: @Bofrostmann I did more changes but without the rest of your code it's just guessing. Try now

Comment: I think this could work now?
`resultList = products.stream()
                .flatMap(product -> regions.stream()
                        .flatMap(region -> Arrays.stream(SalesType.values())
                                .flatMap(salesType -> new SalesRequest(getConnection(),
                                        product.getProductMainGroup(), product.getSbu(), planYear, currentPeriod, region, salesType,
                                        exchangeRates).calculateSalesKpis().stream())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Same idea :D yes thank you! Sorry for that bad formatting..still new to Stack Overflow..